# Find bivariate generating function for two-dimensional sequence

Tags: co.combinatorics, generating-functions, recurrences

How to find generating function for triangle of squares of elements in [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A008949)? I. e. for 
$1 + (1 + 4x)y + (1 + 9x + 16x^2)y^2 + ...$ ? It seems that ordinary approach with arithmetic transformations of recurrence relation not working here. Can one be sure that this OGF is rational/algebraic/representable with elementary functions?

EDIT: This triangle gives numbers of bipolar vectors (having only -1 and +1 as coordinates) dominated by any vector in vectors returned by this Python function:

```
def get_symm_vectors(k, half_len):
    vs = get_vectors_2(half_len) # all bipolar vectors
    limit_vs = [v for v in vs if v.count(-1) == k]
    limit_vs = [tuple(reversed(v)) + v for v in limit_vs]
    limit_vs.sort()
    return limit_vs
```

Example of output if half_len = 5 and k = 3:

```
[
    (-1, -1, -1, +1, +1, +1, +1, -1, -1, -1)
    (-1, -1, +1, -1, +1, +1, -1, +1, -1, -1)
    (-1, -1, +1, +1, -1, -1, +1, +1, -1, -1)
    (-1, +1, -1, -1, +1, +1, -1, -1, +1, -1)
    (-1, +1, -1, +1, -1, -1, +1, -1, +1, -1)
    (-1, +1, +1, -1, -1, -1, -1, +1, +1, -1)
    (+1, -1, -1, -1, +1, +1, -1, -1, -1, +1)
    (+1, -1, -1, +1, -1, -1, +1, -1, -1, +1)
    (+1, -1, +1, -1, -1, -1, -1, +1, -1, +1)
    (+1, +1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, +1, +1)
]
```

Vector $v0$ is dominated by $v1$ if $v0$ has less or equal count of $-1$ then $v1$ and position of ($i$-th from end) $-1$ in $v0$ is less or equal to position of ($i$-th from end) $-1$ in $v1$ for all $i$. Example:
$(1, -1, 1, -1)$ is dominated by $(1, 1, -1, -1)$
$(1, 1, 1, -1)$ is not dominated by $(1, -1, -1, 1)$

Comment: I cannot see the formula for this series. Your link seems to point to a different sequence.

Comment: Just square each element in EXAMPLE section.

Comment: I see, but I doubt there is an explicit formula for the power series.

Comment: In plain words, the question is about $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty y^n\sum_{k=0}^n x^k\left(\sum_{i=0}^k{n\choose i}\right)^2.$$ What it is good for?!